# what is the difference between tkinter sticky formats

Tags: python, tkinter, sticky

I'm trying to learn tkinter but I haven't been able to find an answer that explains why I see examples of the 'sticky' option written in different formats, for example:

```
enter sticky = N+E+S+W
sticky=NW
sticky="ew"
sticky=tk.W+tk.N
```

Is there any significance to the capitalization (I think normally signifies a constant), the + signs (string concatination), and the tk. (a method). Is it personal preference, do they do different things, or does it depend on the context they are being used in?

Comment: tk.E or tk.W is just a string 'e' or 'w'. I think they are just defined for convenience.

Comment: There is almost no difference between them. They both are literals with just different data type

Comment: yes, `N`, `S`, `E`, `W`  are simply constants that holds `'n'`, `'s'`, `'e'`, `'w'` respectively.  For example, using `math.pi` would be the same as using `3.141592653589793`. `N+E+S+W` <- This is nothing but a string concatenation. You can use `N`, `S`, `E`, `W` when you import using [wildcard](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/maintainability/from_module_import_all_used.html#:~:text=wildcard%20imports%20(%20from%20%E2%80%A6-,import%20*%20),program%20that%20imported%20the%20module.) and `tk.N` etc when you are using the `as` keyword in the import (alias).

Comment: @Sujay: _"There is almost_no difference between them. They both are literals with just different data type "_ . That is incorrect, they are both the same datatype because they are both strings. There is literally no difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`N`, `S`, `E`, and `W` are constants defined by the tkinter module. These each contain a string with a single character matching the name (eg: `N = "n"`). Because they are global constants, they are uppercase to be compliant with [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

The reason you sometimes see the constants prefixed with `tk.` or `tkinter` has to do with how the constants are imported. If you do `from tkinter import *` you don't use the prefix. If you use `import tkinter` you use the `tkinter.` prefix. if you use `import tkinter as tk` you use the `tk.` prefix. This isn't anything unique to tkinter, it's how importing works in all of python.

The `sticky` attribute requires a string. That is the only thing it accepts. The string can contain any of the characters "n", "s", "e", "w". Tkinter doesn't care how you create the string. You can pass `"nsew"`, `"news"`, `N + "e" + "s" + W` or any other technique.

Personally, I find the constants useless.  It's much easier just to use the literal string.